# Can't Find App In Android Market

Tags: android

So I published an App to the market, however, I can't find it through my phone and I can't find it through market.google.com. I tried using my title from my publish acct, and tried to use the package in my manifest neither worked.

Does it take a while?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will take a couple of hours to show up on your device - provided the app is available for your device. Some possible filters that would prevent the app from showing up on the market in your phone would be the screen sizes that your application supports, as well as the OS version that is supported both on the device, and what was chosen for the app.

Answer (score 4):

It does indeed take a while. Make sure your app is shown as 'Published' to the right in your Android Market console. After some time you will be able to find it on market.google.com, and after some more time - on your device.

Answer (score 3):

In the developer console, click your app, and go the bottom where supported devices is. Make sure your device is listed. If not, try to find out what in your Manifest might be filtering out certain devices.

I have also discovered that some phones will not show apps that have copy protection turned on in the developer console.

Comment: Where do I see that, NM I found it yes my nexus one is listed